# HTML5 Canvas: How to create multiple shapes in one canvas and position/style them independently

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm new to using HTML canvas and am hoping to be able to create a button that can be transformed and interacted with using the canvas. But I'm struggling to draw the multiple component parts and style/adjust them independently.

For basics, I'm looking for a grey circle with a heart outline in the centre, almost filling the grey circle. The circle will be drawn using `.arc` and the heart outline is an `svg path`.

1) How do I have multiple shapes on the canvas that I can manipulate independently from one another? I started by creating multiple contexts of the same canvas, is this right? E.g `circleContext` and `heartContext` so that I could set different `fill` colours and such only to specific contexts. Is this the correct approach?

2) How do I position these shapes on the canvas? I have set up `canvasCentreX` and `canvasCentreY` with the hope of using these co-ordinates to set shapes where I want them but I cannot seem to position the `path2D` correctly using `.moveTo` or any of the other available methods.

Here is what I have:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMZxvq

```js
// Canvas setup
const canvas = document.getElementById('saveButtonCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasCentreX = canvas.width / 2;
const canvasCentreY = canvas.height / 2;

// Draw grey background circle
const circleContext  = canvas.getContext('2d');
const backgroundCircleRadius = canvas.width / 2;
circleContext.beginPath();
circleContext.arc(canvasCentreX, canvasCentreY, backgroundCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
circleContext.fillStyle = '#eee';
circleContext.fill();

// Draw outline of heart
const heartContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
heartContext.lineWidth = 2;
const heartOutline = new Path2D("M12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 C11.2594659,0.00100271425 9.94933816,0.599893524 8.99600456,1.56687138 C8.04033388,0.603290635 6.72923238,0.00779693764 5.28238554,0.00959540854 C2.36181543,0.0127926901 -0.00252980442,2.44652348 2.03149576e-06,5.44317565 C0.00837656568,12.3289212 9.01294838,16 9.01294838,16 C9.01294838,16 18.0097299,12.3067401 17.9999921,5.41919604 C17.9962917,2.42234403 15.6261038,-0.00339354795 12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 L12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 Z");
heartOutline.moveTo(canvasCentreX, canvasCentreY);
heartContext.stroke(heartOutline);
```

```css
#saveButtonCanvas {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin:30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="saveButtonCanvas" width="80" height="80"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wow I would do it: first I need the size of the svg path. In order to get the size you can draw the svg path inside an svg element and use the getBBox() method. This method is returning an object with the size and the coords of the bounding box. I use the width and the height.

You need to get the context only once.

To move the heart in the center of your canvas I would use `translate`

```js
// Canvas setup
const canvas = document.getElementById('saveButtonCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasCentreX = canvas.width / 2;
const canvasCentreY = canvas.height / 2;

// Draw grey background circle
//const circleContext  = canvas.getContext('2d');
const backgroundCircleRadius = canvas.width / 2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(canvasCentreX, canvasCentreY, backgroundCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#eee';
ctx.fill();

// Draw outline of heart
//const heartContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
const hw = 18;// width of the heart
const hh = 16;// height of the heart


ctx.save();
// translate the heart in the center of the canvas
ctx.translate(-hw/2, -hh/2);
ctx.translate(canvasCentreX,canvasCentreY);

const heartOutline = new Path2D("M12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 C11.2594659,0.00100271425 9.94933816,0.599893524 8.99600456,1.56687138 C8.04033388,0.603290635 6.72923238,0.00779693764 5.28238554,0.00959540854 C2.36181543,0.0127926901 -0.00252980442,2.44652348 2.03149576e-06,5.44317565 C0.00837656568,12.3289212 9.01294838,16 9.01294838,16 C9.01294838,16 18.0097299,12.3067401 17.9999921,5.41919604 C17.9962917,2.42234403 15.6261038,-0.00339354795 12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 L12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 Z");

ctx.stroke(heartOutline);
ctx.restore();
```

```css
#saveButtonCanvas {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin:30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="saveButtonCanvas" width="80" height="80"></canvas>
```

In the case you need to draw a bigger heart I would use scale:

```js
// Canvas setup
const canvas = document.getElementById('saveButtonCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasCentreX = canvas.width / 2;
const canvasCentreY = canvas.height / 2;

// Draw grey background circle
//const circleContext  = canvas.getContext('2d');
const backgroundCircleRadius = canvas.width / 2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(canvasCentreX, canvasCentreY, backgroundCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#eee';
ctx.fill();

// Draw outline of heart
//const heartContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
const hw = 18;// the width of the heart
const hh = 16;// the height of the heart

let scale = 3;// the scale for the heart

ctx.save();

ctx.translate(-scale*hw/2, -scale*hh/2);
ctx.translate(canvasCentreX,canvasCentreY);
ctx.scale(scale,scale)
const heartOutline = new Path2D("M12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 C11.2594659,0.00100271425 9.94933816,0.599893524 8.99600456,1.56687138 C8.04033388,0.603290635 6.72923238,0.00779693764 5.28238554,0.00959540854 C2.36181543,0.0127926901 -0.00252980442,2.44652348 2.03149576e-06,5.44317565 C0.00837656568,12.3289212 9.01294838,16 9.01294838,16 C9.01294838,16 18.0097299,12.3067401 17.9999921,5.41919604 C17.9962917,2.42234403 15.6261038,-0.00339354795 12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 L12.7047547,3.56374623e-06 Z");

ctx.stroke(heartOutline);

ctx.restore();
```

```css
#saveButtonCanvas {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin:30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="saveButtonCanvas" width="80" height="80"></canvas>
```

I hope this helps.